# A Cartesian equation for the complex ellipse equation on $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have the ellipse equation, for $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ constants and $r>0$ the ellipse is defined as the solution to the equation:
$$|z-a|+|z-b|=r$$

I am trying to find from this equation a cartesian formula in coordinate $x,y$ of $z=x+iy$.
So I tried to plug $z=x+iy$ back into $|z-a|+|z-b|=r$, and got stuck maple gives me some nasty looking equation.

Here's my attempt at solving this:
$a=a_1+ia_2$, $b=b_1+ib_2$, $z=x+iy$:
$$r^2 = (x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2+(x-b_1)^2+(y-b_2)^2+2\sqrt{[(x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2]}\sqrt{[(x-b_1)^2+(y-b_2)^2]}$$

Here's where I am not sure how to continue, another squaring of the sqrt after moving the squared terms to the LHS.
Looks too much for me.

Maple gives the two roots of x after typing the following code:

```
solve({sqrt((x - a1)^2 + (y - a2)^2) + sqrt((x - b1)^2 + (y - b2)^2) = r}, {x})

{x = (a1^3 - a1^2*b1 + a1*a2^2 - 2*a1*a2*y - a1*b1^2 - a1*b2^2 + 2*a1*b2*y - a1*r^2 - a2^2*b1 + 2*a2*b1*y + b1^3 + b1*b2^2 - 2*b1*b2*y - b1*r^2 + sqrt(a1^4*r^2 - 4*a1^3*b1*r^2 + 2*a1^2*a2^2*r^2 - 4*a1^2*a2*r^2*y + 6*a1^2*b1^2*r^2 + 2*a1^2*b2^2*r^2 - 4*a1^2*b2*r^2*y - 2*a1^2*r^4 + 4*a1^2*r^2*y^2 - 4*a1*a2^2*b1*r^2 + 8*a1*a2*b1*r^2*y - 4*a1*b1^3*r^2 - 4*a1*b1*b2^2*r^2 + 8*a1*b1*b2*r^2*y + 4*a1*b1*r^4 - 8*a1*b1*r^2*y^2 + a2^4*r^2 - 4*a2^3*r^2*y + 2*a2^2*b1^2*r^2 - 2*a2^2*b2^2*r^2 + 4*a2^2*b2*r^2*y - 2*a2^2*r^4 + 4*a2^2*r^2*y^2 - 4*a2*b1^2*r^2*y + 4*a2*b2^2*r^2*y - 8*a2*b2*r^2*y^2 + 4*a2*r^4*y + b1^4*r^2 + 2*b1^2*b2^2*r^2 - 4*b1^2*b2*r^2*y - 2*b1^2*r^4 + 4*b1^2*r^2*y^2 + b2^4*r^2 - 4*b2^3*r^2*y - 2*b2^2*r^4 + 4*b2^2*r^2*y^2 + 4*b2*r^4*y + r^6 - 4*r^4*y^2))/(2*(a1^2 - 2*a1*b1 + b1^2 - r^2))}, {x = -(-a1^3 + a1^2*b1 - a1*a2^2 + 2*a1*a2*y + a1*b1^2 + a1*b2^2 - 2*a1*b2*y + a1*r^2 + a2^2*b1 - 2*a2*b1*y - b1^3 - b1*b2^2 + 2*b1*b2*y + b1*r^2 + sqrt(a1^4*r^2 - 4*a1^3*b1*r^2 + 2*a1^2*a2^2*r^2 - 4*a1^2*a2*r^2*y + 6*a1^2*b1^2*r^2 + 2*a1^2*b2^2*r^2 - 4*a1^2*b2*r^2*y - 2*a1^2*r^4 + 4*a1^2*r^2*y^2 - 4*a1*a2^2*b1*r^2 + 8*a1*a2*b1*r^2*y - 4*a1*b1^3*r^2 - 4*a1*b1*b2^2*r^2 + 8*a1*b1*b2*r^2*y + 4*a1*b1*r^4 - 8*a1*b1*r^2*y^2 + a2^4*r^2 - 4*a2^3*r^2*y + 2*a2^2*b1^2*r^2 - 2*a2^2*b2^2*r^2 + 4*a2^2*b2*r^2*y - 2*a2^2*r^4 + 4*a2^2*r^2*y^2 - 4*a2*b1^2*r^2*y + 4*a2*b2^2*r^2*y - 8*a2*b2*r^2*y^2 + 4*a2*r^4*y + b1^4*r^2 + 2*b1^2*b2^2*r^2 - 4*b1^2*b2*r^2*y - 2*b1^2*r^4 + 4*b1^2*r^2*y^2 + b2^4*r^2 - 4*b2^3*r^2*y - 2*b2^2*r^4 + 4*b2^2*r^2*y^2 + 4*b2*r^4*y + r^6 - 4*r^4*y^2))/(2*(a1^2 - 2*a1*b1 + b1^2 - r^2))}
```

Is there a way to simplify maple's solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Letting $$H=r^2-(x-a_1)^2-(y-a_2)^2-(x-b_1)^2-(y-b_2)^2,$$ $$L=4((x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2)((x-b_1)^2+(y-b_2)^2)$$ and factoring $$H^2-L$$ works in SAGE. I guess Maple may also work.

Answer (score 1):

To complete my comment, the Cartesian equation $L-H^2=0$ (with a different sign as in the comment) is of the following form:

$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0,$$ where $$A=-4a_1^2 + 8a_1b_1 - 4b_1^2 + 4r^2,$$
$$B=-8a_1a_2 + 8a_2b_1 + 8a_1b_2 - 8b_1b_2,$$
$$C=-4a_2^2 + 8a_2b_2 - 4b_2^2 + 4r^2,$$
$$D=4a_1^3 + 4a_1a_2^2 - 4a_1^2b_1 - 4a_2^2b_1 - 4a_1b_1^2 + 4b_1^3 -
4a_1b_2^2 + 4b_1b_2^2 - 4a_1r^2 - 4b_1r^2,$$
$$E=4a_1^2a_2 + 4a_2^3 - 4a_2b_1^2 - 4a_1^2b_2 - 4a_2^2b_2 + 4b_1^2b_2 -
4a_2b_2^2 + 4b_2^3 - 4a_2r^2 - 4b_2r^2,$$ and
$$F=-a_1^4 - 2a_1^2a_2^2 - a_2^4 + 2a_1^2b_1^2 + 2a_2^2b_1^2 - b_1^4 +
2a_1^2b_2^2 + 2a_2^2b_2^2 - 2b_1^2b_2^2 - b_2^4 + 2a_1^2r^2 + 2a_2^2r^2
+ 2b_1^2r^2 + 2b_2^2r^2 - r^4.$$ This agrees with the approach (with work omitted here) by starting from the standard equation, and then making translation and rotation. When $$(a_1,a_2)=(-3,0),(b_1,b_2)=(3,0),r=10,$$ the equation gives $$6400\left(\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}-1\right)=0,$$ as expected.